# Is there a single word meaning "good night vision"

Tags: single-word-requests

Nyctalopia is a medical condition meaning poor night vision.  Is there an equivalent single word meaning good night vision, either in medical or general parlance?

Comment: When you ask about "good" eyesight in poor or dim light, do you mean "normal" vision or something which expresses a heightened or increased ability to see in the *dark* (night time)  or in conditions of reduced light. Why does it have to be one word? The phenomenon might be expressed in more than one word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I was looking for one word because "good night vision" is a clumsy phrase to use repeatedly.  I am trying to express the idea of a better than average ability for a human to see at night, without implying anything superhuman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Scotopia**

> noun:    the ability of the eye to adjust for night vision - *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scotopia)*

This might not be quite what you're looking for because it is just the ability to see "normally" in the dark, but perhaps you could do something with it?

Comment: Maybe euscotopia should be a word?  Not sure I can get away with that though.

Answer (score 10):

[Night-sight](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=night-sight):

> - the ability to see in reduced illumination (as in moonlight);

or [night vision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night-sight):

> - ***is the ability to see in low light conditions***. Whether by biological or technological means, night vision is made possible by a combination of two approaches: sufficient spectral range, and sufficient intensity range. Humans have poor night vision compared to many animals, in part because the human eye lacks a tapetum lucidum.(Wikipedia)

also : [night-eyed](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=night-eyed):

> - Capable of seeing at night; ***sharp-eyed***. "Your night-eyed
>     Tiberius." --B. Jonson.
>     [1913 Webster]

Comment: I like the poetry of night-eyed, although I see that every dictionary I can find refers back to the Webster definition which, in turn, seems to have only the one reference in Jonson.

Comment: Yes, but I  thought it was  worth mentioning.

Comment: @Alchymist OED gives three citations.
1605   B. Jonson Sejanus v. i. 363,   "I dare tell you..That our Night-ey'd Tiberius doth not see His Minions driftes.";
1838   R. Southey Madoc ii. xxvi, in Poet. Wks. V. 376   "The night-eyed insect tribes Wake to their portion of the circling hours.";
1999   Star Tribune (Minneapolis) (Nexis) 6 Mar. 7 b,   "April 15 creeps up on us in the dark, staring like some kind of night-eyed beast.".

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could inject a word into common parlance.  Since people who see well at a distance are *eagle-eyed*, people who see well at night should be *owl-eyed*,

Answer (score 1):

**Increased night vision**

> (colloquial) A person with the medical condition Systemic lupus erythematosus, colloquially known as vampirism, with effects such as photosensitivity, brownish-red stained teeth, and *increased night vision*. ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:vampire))

Comment: I'm not sure vampirism has quite the connotations I was looking for but I like the idea.

Comment: Incidentally, in this context "photosensitivity" means that your skin, not your eyes, is [particularly sensitive to light](https://www.avforums.com/styles/avf/editorial/products/26b864ae0defab8ffbb73a2ca34a1e71_8193.jpg).

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a single word, otherwise we could all suggest *"heightened / enhanced / elevated / excellent night  (nocturnal) vision"*

Answer (score 1):

Hyperscotopia? Scotopia is from the greek, as is hyper which is a common qualifying prefix in medical terminology.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). As this is a Q&A website, supporting your answer with authoritative references is strongly encouraged - please consider adding some to improve your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Hemeralopia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hemeralopia) might be somewhat the word you are looking for:

> a condition of the eyes in which the sufferer can see clearly at night but has impaired vision during the day; day blindness.

Comment: the OP is looking for _good_ night vision, not bad _day_ vision.

Comment: I know, but he asked for a good night vision, and this condition implies it. Just that it goes with bad day vision as well.

Comment: Hemeralopia implies normal night vision with reduced day vision.  Confusingly, it has also been used for night blindness in some circumstances, as http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1857511/ discusses.

Comment: @Alchymist: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemeralopia) says that hemeralopia is the exact opposite of nyctalopia.

Comment: @emanen - no arguments that hemeralopia *should* mean day blindness.     The distinction has caused confusion in the past, however.

Answer (score 0):

Plain night vision would be *nycteropia*. If you want to coin a word, I would suggest:

***nycteroptasia***

This means something similar, night-seeing, night-appearing, night-illuminating. It is stronger than *-opia*, so it probably a good way to convey the basic idea.

Comment: Per every online eymology source I can find, nyctalopia is actually formed from nykt- (from nyx) meaning night, alaos meaning blind, and ops meaning eye. So that would in fact specifically mean lack of night vision, night-blindness.

Comment: @recognizer Thanks for pointing that out, the subtleties of medical word formation. I have adjusted my answer appropriately.

Answer (score -3):

**[Nocturnal](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=nocturnal&button=Search)**

> 1. belonging to or active during the night;
> 2. of or relating to or occurring in the night;

This doesn't strictly mean good eye sight at night, but it could be implied depending on context.